# How to get the result of send-keys in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I am using tmux to run a server console. To check whether the console is answering, I would like to use `send-keys` to run a command on the console:

```
tmux send-keys -t mysess:mywin "show info" Enter
```

(Actually, I’m currently logging the full console output to a file and reading the last line, but I hope that a better solution exists.)

```
tmux pipe-pane -o -t mysess:mywin 'cat >> mysess-mywin.log'
```

Comment: Try to add the tag for the OS you are using - this will help others to find your question and answer it. [tmux] tag has only 75 followers.

Comment: You won't see the output of `show info`, since it will appear in `mysess:mywin`, not the window where you executed the `send-keys` command.

Answer (score 10):

The context of how you are accessing the output will impact whether this solution is better or not, but this might work:

```
tmux send-keys -t <session:win.pane> '<command>' Enter
tmux capture-pane -t <session:win.pane> 
tmux show-buffer
```

You should be able to play with the `-S`, and `-E` options of `capture-pane`, as well as the size of the pane, to accurately capture the output. If you're so inclined, you could also use `show-panes` and a small regexp to capture the height of the pane, and then just use `-S <height - 1>` to capture just the last line.

It's then simple to read this from another program like so (e.g., in python):

```
print Popen(['tmux', 'show-buffer'], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Comment: I wonder what do you mean by `show-panes` , but one can just use `tmux ... capture-pane | tail -1` to get the last line

Answer (score 0):

one option is to call a script with send-keys that runs 'show info' and have the script 'send-keys' back the results to the tmux session you are on. this only works if you are in tmux to begin with.