# How can Python Read the Stdout of a Detached screen Session in Ubuntu/Linux?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu, stdout

How can a Python script running on an Ubuntu system read the Stdout of a program that is running in a `screen` session?

```
screen

## Now inside screen session...

./run_something

## Detach from screen...

python readScreenStdout.py     <--- can this script read the output to the screen session?
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want to use `screen -L` logging,
or tmux `show-buffer` or `pipe-pane` (or possibly `capture-pane`).

Soupso obtained good results [via a named pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49031841/how-to-get-stdout-and-stderr-from-a-tmux-session#answer-49067242).